# React Native Access State from StyleSheet

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set the background of a container based on the state but it keeps showing me an error **bg is not defined**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        bg:'#fff'
    }
}

render(){
    return(<View style={styles.container} />)
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: this.state.bg,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this code:

```
return <View style={[styles.container, backgroundColor: this.state.bg]}/>
```

for this code:

```
return <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.state.bg}]}/>
```

Comment: Also you can destructure state and can use just `backgroundColor: bg`

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment below and use like it

[image]

Comment: would it make a difference if i use just inline styling ?

Comment: it will not make any difference..  it will work same like creating styles.

Comment: Actually, its working with inline styling, my question was doesn't it make any difference when it comes to performance because style sheet is better than inline styling for performance but i have never tried using in render function as your code above

Comment: You are correct that it have performance issues because whenever render function called, it needs to create style. But generally for such small code it does not have performance issues. So you can use it like it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really, however what you can do is use it within the style of the container like so:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     bg:'#fff'
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1
    }})
render(){
  return <View style={[styles.container, backgroundColor: this.state.bg]}/>
}
```

Comment: so only Inline styling will work in this case, thanks

Comment: ur code has some error, I dont think we can use bracket in the style?